# Conversão do tipo VARCHAR para SMALLDATETIME

Tags: sql-server

```html
    SELECT DISTINCT p.codInterno,
                CASE
                    WHEN f.idFabricante IS NULL THEN 99999999999999
                    ELSE f.idFabricante
                END AS fabri,
                '0', 
                p.descResumida, 
                p.descProduto,
                p.descProduto,
                p.codElemento,
                GETDATE(),
                GETDATE(),
                0,
                0  
    FROM    [HORPDB00\PDBSIAC].[SiacPRD].[dbo].[IntPluProduto] p
        INNER JOIN  [HORPDB00\PDBSIAC].[SiacPRD].[dbo].[IntControle] c on c.idProcesso = p.idProcesso
        LEFT JOIN [HORPDB00\VANR].[tlmark].[dbo].[Produto] vanProduto on vanProduto.CdPrdSAP = p.codInterno
        LEFT JOIN tbFabricante f on f.idFabricante = CAST(vanProduto.CdFbr AS int)
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS(select 1 from tbProduto where idSAP = p.codInterno)
    AND vanProduto.cdFbr <> 'NNN0'
    AND CAST(c.dtHrProcesso AS DATE) > DATEADD(ss, 64800, DATEADD(d, -1, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS smalldatetime))) 
    OR CAST(c.dtHrProcesso AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    AND c.codModulo = 14
    AND vanProduto.ICMSubst <> 'T'
```

Neste ponto:

```
AND CAST(c.dtHrProcesso AS DATE) > DATEADD(ss, 64800, DATEADD(d, -1, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS smalldatetime))) 
    OR CAST(c.dtHrProcesso AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

O filtro acima não faz nada além de, partindo da data atual, subtrai 1 dia, e após adiciona 18 horas (64800 segundos).
Por exemplo, para a data atual 27/12/2016 06:00:00:
Subtrai 1 dia: 26/12/2016 06:00:00
Formata o resultado para: 26/12/2016 00:00:00
Adiciona 64800 segundos (18hrs): 26/12/2016 18:00:00

> Erro de conversão: The conversion of a varchar data type to a
>   smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema deve ser no formato da data, que provavelmente está diferente do banco de dados.

O comando `CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 103)` retorna a data no formato dd/mm/yyyy, por conta do formato "103", mas se seu banco estiver configurado para `US` por exemplo não irá funcionar. O problema acontece na verdade no `CAST`, não no `CONVERT`.

Você pode identificar a linguagem do banco nas propriedades, ou usando o comando `select @@language`

Fiz esse teste aqui no SQL 2012 e aconteceu o mesmo erro. Substituindo o formato por "101" (meu SQL está configurado em `us_english`), funcionou perfeitamente:

```
select CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS smalldatetime)
```

Comment: --teste, data anterior apartir das 18:00 horas 
 SELECT DATEADD(ss, 64800, DATEADD(d, -1, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 120) AS smalldatetime)))

Comment: Não entendi, você quer que eu teste essa linha? Aqui retornou *2016-12-26 18:00:00*

Answer (score 0):

> O filtro acima não faz nada além de, partindo da data atual, subtrai 1
>   dia, e após adiciona 18 horas

"partindo da data atual"
     **A**= Cast (Current_Timestamp as date)

"subtrai um dia"
     **B**= DateAdd (day, -1, A)

"adiciona 18 horas"
     **C**= DateAdd (hour, +18, Cast(B as datetime))

Juntando tudo, temos:
  DateAdd(hour, +18, Cast( DateAdd(day, -1, Cast(Current_Timestamp as date)) as datetime) )

Me parece que a cláusula WHERE ficaria assim:

```
WHERE c.dtHrProcesso > DateAdd(hour, 
                               +18,
                               Cast( DateAdd(day, -1, Cast(Current_Timestamp as date)) as datetime) )
```

---

Melhor ainda se montar algo semelhante a

```
-- código #1
declare @Ontem18h datetime;
set @Ontem18h= DateAdd(hour, 
                       +18, 
                       Cast( DateAdd(day, -1, Cast(Current_Timestamp as date)) as datetime) );

SELECT ...
  from ...
  where c.dtHrProcesso > @Ontem18h;
```

Observe que como a coluna cdtHrProcesso é do tipo datetime, então a variável @Ontem18h foi declarada no mesmo tipo, evitando assim a conversão implícita.

Comment: Fiz assim:  --teste, data anterior apartir das 18:00 horas 
 SELECT DATEADD(ss, 64800, DATEADD(d, -1, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 120) AS smalldatetime)))

Comment: @itasouza: existe um princípio chamado KISS ("keep it simple, stupid"). Algo como "mantenha o mais simples possível". Evite misturar tipos (smalldatetime, varchar etc) para algo tão simples como encontrar as 18h do dia anterior. Sempre que possível crie códigos que sejam independentes de LANGUAGE e/ou DATEFORMAT.

Comment: @JoséDiz Você chegou a executar o código que postou? DateAdd(hour, +18, DateAdd(day, -1, Cast(Current_Timestamp as date))) - A função de data dateadd não dá suporte à datepart hour para o tipo de dados date. Realmente, como você sugeriu, a utilização de expressões usando tipos data (date, datetime etc) em T-SQL requer certo conhecimento e experiência.

Comment: @E.Thomas. Corrigido. B foi convertido para o tipo datetime antes de calcular C.